# Keep StreamSubscription alive while navigating views

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to keep my StreamSubscription of locationData alive as I navigate from Parent view to child view and back to parent view so that I can have total data as and when required on the parent view.

```
StreamSubscription<LocationData>? _locationSubscription;
Future<void> _listenLocation() async {
    _locationSubscription =
        location.onLocationChanged.handleError((dynamic err) {
      if (err is PlatformException) {}
      _locationSubscription?.cancel();
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _locationSubscription = null;
        });
      }
    }).listen((LocationData currentLocation) async {
      DateTime now = DateTime.now();
      var currentTimeStamp = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(now);
      coordinates.add([
        currentLocation.latitude,
        currentLocation.longitude,
        currentTimeStamp
      ]);
      dev.log(
          'Location: ${currentLocation.latitude}, ${currentLocation.longitude}, $currentTimeStamp');
    });
  }
```

I tried passing the _locationSubscription as a parameter to the child view.

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ChildView(
            triggerCheck:
                widget.triggerCheck,
            locationSubscription:
                _locationSubscription,
          )),
);
    
class ChildView extends StatefulWidget {
  final int triggerCheck;
  final locationSubscription;
  ChildView(
      {super.key,
      this.triggerCheck = 0,
      this.locationSubscription});

  @override
  State<ChildView> createState() => _ChildViewState();
}
```

And on redirect back to parent view I passed widget.locationSubscription back hoping that it would provide the data back.

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => ParentView(
      triggerCheck: 1,
      locationSubscription: widget.locationSubscription,
    ),
  ),
);
```

And in initState of parent view I have set `_locationSubscription = widget.locationSubscription when widget.triggerCheck = 1`. But the output is null.